# Pandas MultiIndex Dataframe Groupby Rolling Mean

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to calculate Rolling Mean of dataframe groupby second level (Key2 in following code sample).

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'Key1':[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,6,6,6], 'Key2':[2,7,8,5,3,2,7,5,8,7,2,9,8,3,9,2,7,9],'Value':[1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df = df.set_index(['Key1', 'Key2'])
df['MA'] = (df.groupby('Key2')['Value']
                .rolling(window=3)
                .mean()
                .reset_index(level=0, drop=True))

print(df)
```

Expected output:

```
           Value        MA
Key1 Key2                 
1    2         1       NaN
     7         2       NaN
     8         3       NaN
2    5         1       NaN
     3         2       NaN
     2         3       NaN
3    7         1       NaN
     5         2       NaN
     8         3       NaN
4    7         1  1.333333
     2         2  2.000000
     9         3       NaN
5    8         1  2.333333
     3         2       NaN
     9         3       NaN
6    2         1  2.000000
     7         2  1.333333
     9         3  3.000000
```

But the actual output is NaN. It seems something wrong with the assignment.
Actual output:

```
           Value        MA
Key1 Key2                 
1    2         1       NaN
     7         2       NaN
     8         3       NaN
2    5         1       NaN
     3         2       NaN
     2         3       NaN
3    7         1       NaN
     5         2       NaN
     8         3       NaN
4    7         1      NaN
     2         2       NaN
     9         3       NaN
5    8         1      NaN
     3         2       NaN
     9         3       NaN
6    2         1      NaN
     7         2       NaN
     9         3       NaN
```

Python 3.8 + Pandas 1.2.1. (Also tried on Python 3.7.9 + Pandas 1.1.5)

Comment: Yes, that's the expected behavior. By rolling(3), you only get non-nan values for `Key2` with `>=3` rows. You can pass `min_periods=1` to `rolling(3, min_periods=1)`. Is it what you expect?

Comment: @Quang Hoang, I didn’t get the expected output. Please see the updated actual output.

Comment: The code returns the expected output on my system. You may have different Pandas version. You can try to print the `groupby().rolling().mean()` series to see if `reset_index` is needed.

Comment: Could you please advise the version of python&pandas in your system?

Comment: Python 3.7 and Pandas 1.1.4.

Comment: I tried out Python 3.7.9 and Pandas 1.1.5, still got the all NaN output.  Without .reset_index, exception is raised saying "cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use lambda function for avoid lost `MultiIndex`, so assign working well:

```
df['MA'] = df.groupby('Key2')['Value'].apply(lambda x: x.rolling(window=3).mean())
print(df)
           Value        MA
Key1 Key2                 
1    2         1       NaN
     7         2       NaN
     8         3       NaN
2    5         1       NaN
     3         2       NaN
     2         3       NaN
3    7         1       NaN
     5         2       NaN
     8         3       NaN
4    7         1  1.333333
     2         2  2.000000
     9         3       NaN
5    8         1  2.333333
     3         2       NaN
     9         3       NaN
6    2         1  2.000000
     7         2  1.333333
     9         3  3.000000
```